# Is it possible to detect "The number format applied to this cell may be misleading" with VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Here's a simple macro that creates a worksheet that has a cell with a *The number format applied to this cell may be misleading* warning (indicated by the green triangle).

```
Sub createWarning()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = 98765.4321
    ws.Cells(1, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "= RC[-1]"
    ws.Cells(1, 2).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"
End Sub
```

[image]

I'd like to be able to detect such warnings with VBA. Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/misleading-formats-error-f31b6c93-eac4-48a6-8630-ea097f93e5bb

## The note section has Application setting (will show if it is turned on)

> Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.MisleadingNumberFormats property,
> which will return a Boolean (True/False) value.

## The cell level check

```
MsgBox ws.Cells(1, 2).Errors(xlMisleadingFormat).Value
MsgBox ws.Cells(1, 2).Errors(10).Value
```

Comment: The linked page describes how I can turn on or off the check of this particular error - not how I can determine if I have such an error on a given worksheet.

Comment: I added the example of checking cells.  I still think that the application check would be important if releasing solution outside of self use.  If a user has this feature turned off, the expect results of code may not account for this possibility?

Comment: Interesting, the `xlMisleadingFormat` member is of the `XlErrorChecks` enumeration is not documented ( https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlerrorchecks )